# Sddm greeter isn't showing after logout in arch

Tags: linux, kde, logout, display-manager, journalctl

I'm having a problem in arch Linux, i installed kde sddm and when i try to logout i get a black screen with a cursor on it. I've enabled the sddm.service also and everything else works fine except that. I've googled for 5 days but couldn't find a solution. Can anybody tell me why this is happening? Im adding my log file from a boot where i just booted, logged in, logged out (and got that black screen), switch to a parallel tty, logged in as root and rebooted.

http://ix.io/2HLM

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, looking for a solution I found that apparently nvidia drivers load after ssdm and that breaks everything. The only workaraound I found is related to adding a delay to sddm on boot, or restarting ssdm after the boot ends.